# What does this es5 code do and why does it say 'block scope'?

Tags: javascript

What does this es5 code do that emulates es6 const?

Particularly the comments do not make sense as there is no block scope in es5.

http://es6-features.org/#Constants

```
//  only in ES5 through the help of object properties
//  and only in global context and not in a block scope
Object.defineProperty(typeof global === "object" ? global : window, "PI", {
    value:        3.141593,
    enumerable:   true,
    writable:     false,
    configurable: false
})
PI > 3.0;
```

Comment: Yes; that's why they say _not_ in block scope.

Comment: There is no block scope in ES5 so you don't need to comment it, it would be like commenting how an `if` statement works.

Comment: The comment is saying this is the limitation of trying to create a `const` in ES5. It has to be in the global context, and will not be scoped to block scope.

Comment: Nothing about code is specific to ES6.

Comment: @Patrick - nope, you can define a constant property on any object.  Not just the global object ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: @Felix - typo, it is ES5 code emulating ES6 const.

Comment: @jonjonbonbon, yes, but then it is not a variable, it is a property. And is not accessible like a const variable, meaning you have to access it through the object `{}.someconst`. Whereas if you put it on global object you can just do `someconst` which is more inline with simulating `const`

Answer (score 1):

```
typeof global === "object" ? global : window
```

This is a shortcut way of saying this, (basically)

```
var tmp;
if (typeof global  === "object") {
  tmp = global;
} else {
  tmp = window;
}

Object.defineProperty(tmp, "PI",
```

There are environments that JavaScript runs in, such as node, that does not have a `window` property since there is no window.  This lets you create a global variable called `global` and it will use that variable if it exists.  If it does not exist, then it defaults to trying `window`.

Then it create a property on that global object (whatever its name) called `PI`

The rest of the details can be read here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: right, but `this` will point t the global object ( be it window or foo ) ( in strict mode ) so you don't need any of that code.

Comment: my point is , that that bit of code is just fluff that does not add to the value of the over all concept.

Answer (score 1):

> What does this es5 code

It creates a global variable that is readonly.

> Particularly the comments do not make sense as there is no block scope in es5.

The comments are there to explicitly point our the differences to ES6 `const`:

- You can only create readonly "variables" in the global environment, because only the global environment is backed by an object (well, `with` environments too, but who uses that anyway). OTOH, `const` works in any environment.
- Variables created like this are not blocked scope, unlike `const`.

In other words, this code is as close as you can get to the `const` functionality.